# CSS browser compatibility - Nested Divs and Positions

Tags: html, css

Here is my site : rickymason.net/blurbs

If you take a look at it in chrome, you'll see that the AJAX on the right loads properly, and the CSS correctly formats it.

In firefox, its a different story. I've played around with it, but can't find the problem.

Here is my template(divs):

```
<html>
<head><?php echo $head; ?></head>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="topnav"><?php echo $topnav; ?></div>
    <div id="leftbar">
        <?php echo $logo; ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $profile['avatar_loc']['location'] ?>" alt="avatar_user"/>
        <div id="select"> 
            <?php echo $create; ?>
            <div id="filter_select"><?php echo $category; ?></div>
            <div id="addfilter"><?php echo $addfilter; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="boardwrapper"> 
    <div id="boardborder">
        <div id="board" alt="Welcome to Blurb!"><img src="img/board/loading.gif" alt="loading"/></div>
    </div>
    <div id="boardbot"></div>
</div>
<footer>
    <?php echo $footer; ?>
</footer>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.board {
    display: table;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.board #row {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.board #author p {
    position: absolute;
    top: inherit;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 53px;
    color: white;
    font: 16px Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
}

.board #author {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #97cae6;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}

.board #arrow {
    background-image: url('../img/board/corner.jpg');
    display: table-cell;
    width: 35px;
    height: 75px;
}

.board #subject {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 75px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 653px;
    max-width: 653px;
    height: 75px;
    border-top: 1px solid #97cae6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #97cae6;
}

.board #subject a {
    position: absolute;
    top: inherit;
    padding-top: 18px;
}

.board #info {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 180px;
    height: 75px;
    border-top: 1px solid #97cae6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #97cae6;
    border-right: 1px solid #97cae6;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

Hopefully something jumps out at you and you can help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain what happens or set up a jsfiddle.net page.

Comment: Is the format of the CSS whats being screwed up in FireFox? A lot of times sites will look different depending on the browser. The workaround is to create seperate CSS pages for the browser. Name your current with chrome or something like that, then adjust the CSS so it looks good in FireFox and name it FireFox. You can then use javascript to identify the browser and grab the correct CSS file.

Comment: Sorry but that is a horrible suggestion. Imagine creating a separate CSS for every browser. I'd say 95% of the cases of differences in browsers can be manually fixed without the need for hacks or extra CSS. There is no need to create a separate stylesheet for time something does not match from browser to browser, also with the amount of available devices nowadays, imagine managing one css for each one just because the site looks different.

Comment: Up 1 for Pablo, very unmanageable in my experience. It is bad enough when you have to do such hacks for legacy browsers never mind modern webkit based browsers such as firefox which shouldn't need its own style sheet provided that the css is well formed

Comment: Using `display:table-cell;` is not recommended anymore. Sure, it has it's uses, but even those are arguable. However, If you're set on it, you can read about the ins-outs at http://www.digital-web.com/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/. Keeping in mind that this was "cutting edge" in 2008 and never took off, because it isn't that great of a way to layout content.

Comment: @BG_Insight I appreciate the feedback from all.  Relating to your comment BG, do you believe that the way I am using it is acceptable?  I feel like the information displayed is tabular, and it is something i need to dynamically list.  Tables just seem to make the most sense.

Comment: I'm just speaking from experience. Having been down that road when it was the great "**NEW**" thing that all the cool kids were trying and ultimately being disappointed with it, along with a lot of others... some people know the quirks, and like it, but as always, it's your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file **board.css**, changing this:

```
.board #arrow {
background-image: url('../img/board/corner.jpg');
display: table-cell;
width: 35px;
height: 75px;
```

}

to this:

```
.board #arrow {
background: url('../img/board/corner.jpg') no-repeat;
display: table-cell;
width: 35px;
```

}

Should fix your problem.

JA

Comment: this helped a lot.  I should be able to fix the rest. thank you